# Can't resolve VBA Array error 13 type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a subset of an array. I google, read other posts etc, but I couldn't manage it. What am I doing wrong here?

```vb
Dim startIndex As Long
startIndex = 13
Dim myArray As Variant
myArray = tbl.ListRows(x).Range

Dim sortArray As Variant
Dim y, yy As Long
y = 0
yy = 1
For y = startIndex To tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
    sortArray(yy) = myArray(1, y)
    yy = yy + 1
Next
```

At `sortArray(yy)` it says a type mismatch, but I don't see one.
`sortArray(yy)` does mismatch to an integer which is in `myArray(1,y)`?

Comment: You need to give `sortArray` a dimension before trying to fill it. `ReDim sortArray(LBound(myArray, 2) To Ubound(myArray, 2))` since you are filling it with the columns from `myArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Damian that was the issue.

```
    Dim sortArray As Variant
    Dim sortArrayDim As Long
    sortArrayDim = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - startIndex
    ReDim sortArray(sortArrayDim)
    Dim y, yy As Long
    y = 0
    yy = 0
    For y = startIndex To tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
        sortArray(yy) = myArray(1, y)
        yy = yy + 1
    Next
```